# Ruby on Rails questions

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm just wondering before I ask if StackOverflow is the IT site to be asking Ruby-on-rails questions? I'm a little confused by what roles all these IT site fulfill.

Comment: A post about a question about a question. No, it should be on www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: User is asking if they can post Ruby-on-rails questions and secondarily for clarification on the purpose of stack overflow. Both seem pretty on topic for meta.

Answer (score 5):

It's perfectly fine to ask a Ruby on Rails question on StackOverflow. There are plenty of questions on this topic: [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails).